# azure-mobile-apps-client - invokeApi Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

**Setup:**

Using the js library and following the client-side login/auth flow of my C# Xamarin projects.
CORS is setup and initial login is fine:

```
this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(<endpoint>);
this.client.login(<provider>);
```

I store the returned "userId" and "mobileServiceAuthenticationToken" for future use.

**Problem:**

Calling the invokeApi of azure-mobile-apps-client:

```
this.client.invokeApi("myCustomerController", { method: 'GET' })
```

returns:

> 401 (Unauthorized)

Am I missing something?  I'm expecting the client to be ready to make calls to my back-end services.

I've tried using the existing client directly after the login without success.
It also fails when setting the "userId" and "mobileServiceAuthentication token" of a new client.

The custom ApiController I'm calling is working fine when called from elsewhere (such as C# MobileServiceClient).

Comment: Get a trace of the invokeApi call and see what the headers are.  Possibly post them?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the login would get the client ready for use but not in my case.  I had to call login, get the userId and token returned in the result, then set currentUser manually before make any future requests.

```
this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://...");
this.client.currentUser = {
      userId: "xxxxx",
      mobileServiceAuthenticationToken: "xxxxx"}
```

Comment: I used this functionality with the latest version of the client last week, and setting the currentUser property manually wasn't required. It may be something that was fixed in a later version. What version of the client are you using?

Comment: login does set the currentUser when promise fulfils

Answer (score 0):

The *login* method returns a promise. Can you confirm you are indeed waiting for the promise to be fulfilled before proceeding to do an *invokeApi* call?